# Comparing a string against a `string.Format` template

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I've got a class with a method that returns an error message under a certain condition like so:

```
public class MyClass{
     public const string CertainErrorTemplate = "Can't find order {0}";

     public string CheckForCertainError(){
         ...
         else
            return string.Format(CertainErrorTemplate, orderId);
     } 
}
```

How can I best write a unit test that will ensure that the error message that comes back has the same 'form' of the template?  If I hard code part of the string's text in the unit test the test would (in my opinion, incorrectly) break if I updated the verbiage later on...

Also:  same question, except for messages of the form:

```
$"Can't find order {orderId}"
```

I suppose I could create and return message classes that all implement `.ToString()` (and test for `message is MyErrorClass`), but that feels...verbose.  Advice?

Comment: Please provide a problem description and a code which reproduces that problem

Comment: regex? separate classes for your errors/exceptions?

Comment: If you're doing good unit testing, you have a known input and can compare against an known string for the output. If you're pulling a random order from a sample database, that is **not** a real unit test. Race condition bugs aside, a real unit test can **never** fail on one run and then pass on the next just because it pulled a different database value.

Comment: You an use `Assert.True(errorStr.StartsWith/Contains`.  But yeah, what @JoelCoehoorn said.

Comment: dont forget to consider localization and strings changing!

Comment: @Kyle I want to prevent the unit test from breaking if I change the template above.  I don't want to test against a hardcoded string.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy This is design question, and I think it's pretty clear.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I'm not using database values, didn't mean to mislead you; these are purely business logic objects.  I want to future-proof the unit tests against change in verbage (`CertainErrorTemplate `), and to do that I need to be able to test against the template and not a hardcoded string.

Comment: @DanielA.White Separate error/message classes would work in a lot of cases...but there is some code that I'm testing that involves making sure a (generated) entity class member variable ended up with the right content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I hard code part of the string's text in the unit test it would
>   break if I updated the verbiage later on...

Think about your goal. If the goal is to check *whether returned error matches some public template*, then using `CertainErrorTemplate` in the unit test assertion makes sense. Whenever you change `CertainErrorTemplate`, unit test will check if the returned value changed as well. Test will fail when error message format will not match public template.

But usually, the goal is different - you want to check *whether returned message matches some format* - i.e. contain some text with given order id in correct place. And `CertainErrorTemplate` is just an implementation detail which should not bother you. That's why I don't recommend to share string between code and unit test. Even more, if you will occasionally or intentionally change the `CertainErrorTemplate`, your test should fail. E.g. with [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.com/)

```
sut.CheckForCertainError().Should().Be("Can't find order 42")
```

I also recommend not to use hardcoded order id - generate it each time and verify that error message has required format and contains given order id:

```
sut.CheckForCertainError().Should().Be($"Can't find order {generatedId}")
```

It does not matter whether your SUT uses `CertainErrorTemplate` or not - if the actual result does not match expected string, the test should fail. I have already seen some cases when shared strings were used in tests, and after modification of public message templates, none of the tests failed, though actual messages had orthographic errors.

Comment: Good discussion on why I was doing what I was doing...and +1 for teaching me the correct spelling of 'verbiage'

Answer (score 0):

I'd moved the error creation text away from the logic:

```
public interface IErrorMessage{
    void CantFindTemplate(int templateId);
}


public class MyClass{

     private IErrorMessage _errorMessage;

     ctor(IErrorMessage errorMessage){

        _errorMessage = errorMessage

     }

     public string CheckForCertainError(){
         ...
         else
            _exceptionHelper.CantFindTemplate(templateId);
     } 
}
```

then you can verify it within your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little helper method to split the template in its parts and check if all template parts are part of the message:

```
public static void AssertMatchTemplate(string message, string template)
{
    var templateParts = Regex.Split(template,"\\{.*?}")
    foreach (var templatePart in templateParts)
        Assert.IsTrue(message.Contains(templatePart));
}
```